# Stylesheet comment header: Which header names are mandatory?

Tags: templates, css

I've always used the same comment header names in my style.css document. Theme Name, Theme URI, Author etc. For example:

```
/*
Theme Name: Example
Theme URI: http://example.com
Author: John Doe
Author URI: http://example.org
Description: An example.
Version: 1.0.0
Tags: tags
*/
```

Which of these lines are *mandatory*?

Comment: Technically speaking, just `Theme Name: Example`

Comment: @PieterGoosen as an answer please.

Comment: If it's a child theme, don't you now also need Template: [parent name] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking all you need is the `Theme Name` in your stylesheet header. This will identify your theme. All the other info is need-to-know info and can be omitted.

If your theme is a child theme, you will need to have `Template` as well as this will be the path to the parent theme.